# Load frequency calculation of quartz with its load capacitance

Tags: frequency, load, calculation, quartz

After web researches and a [first discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565648/crystal-frequencies) about general comprehension, I am a bit lost with the load frequency calculation:

I see a design which uses two 33pF external capacitors (C1 and C2),with a uC which has two 4pf input capacitors (Cin and Cout) and with an guesstimated stray capacitance of 2pf, the above [formula](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250608/crystal-oscillator-load-capacitance-again/250729) gives a c_load = (4+33)*(4+33)/(4+33+33+4)+2 = 20.5pF

[image]

This design uses this configuration with the following quartz [ECS-.327-CDX-1128](https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/CDX-1128.pdf) which has the following characteristics:

- FL = 32 768Hz (load frequency)
- C0 capacitance = 2 pF (shunt capacitance)
- C1 capacitance = 3,7 pF (mean of 3,0 and 4,4pF) (motional capacitance)
- CL = 6 pF (load capacitance expected to get the load frequency above)

I use the following [formula](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00002187A.pdf) to get the series frequency Fs (thanks to all the quartz characteristics above), which I use then in the same formula but changing the load capacitance value with previous calculated one.

[image]

I got:

- Fs = 26 632 Hz
- Fl (with Cload = 20.5pF) = 28 813 Hz

Even if load capacitance specified is not respected here, I am surprised that the load frequency is such far from the frequency expected. Indeed, this not the same order of magnitude as it can be pointed out at [TI application report](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa322d/slaa322d.pdf?ts=1621495603068&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) , as shown below, where the frequency drift is more about some Hz or ten of Hz (note: this is an example, quartz characteristics are not the same)

[image]

So I guess I am misunderstanding something which makes me make wrong interpretation leading to a wrong calculation. Can you help please ?

I have found another formula [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00221665-oscillator-design-guide-for-stm8afals-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), as shown below, but the result (Fs = 26 070Hz and FL=28 292Hz) are still really far.

[image]

Comment: Hello, any help please =)

Comment: still no help ? :'(